# Is there any way to change size of popup window size for html <input type="date">

Tags: html, css, angular

Is there any way to change default html tag  popup calendar size.
this is my UI. As you can see, input field is bigger than dropdown(popup) calendar size. When i change input size, it only change the field's size but not the size of popup window. Is there any way to make the size of input field and popup html tag  to be matched?
I am using angular to design the UI now.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is no way to change that. If you want to have more functionality in style I suggest to use datepicker. https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: Thanks you for your reply. I have been arranging input fields in grid system. So, the only way to match the size of input field and popup is to adjust input field or use custom datepicker instead of html tag one.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, no.

However, as you are able to resize the input *field* and not the *dropdown*, you can resize it to fit the dropdown.

Hope this answers your question :)